# using ms-word protocol from a react application to open a docx in MS word

Tags: reactjs, ms-word, protocols

Currently trying to allow users to click a button in a react application to open a .docx document in their local version of word.

Have a C# rest endpoint setup that will return a document as a FileStreamResult if you pass it a document id.

Wondering if anyone has accomplished this before as I was eventually hoping that i could pass an endpoint in to the save parameter so once saved it would upload back to the server.

Tried running the ms-word command however it comes up with "this action couldn't be performed because office doesn't recognize the command it was given".  ms-word:ofe|u|<>

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe show some code or the actual error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.